spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled is an unknown property. Is there any alternative. I use spring version 3.2.6
spring.application.name=api-gateway
server.port=8765

#unknown property
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true

I tried to downgrade the version of Spring but nothing helps and I also couldn’t find an answer on the Internet

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I had the same problem as you, after some research I found that I missed a dependency.
I had in my pom the gateway-mvc, however the property was only correctly identified once I included the gateway dependency, without the "MVC":
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-gateway
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-gateway -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4</version>
</dependency>

